# Change CPU MHz from Registry

Tags: windows-registry, cpu-architecture

Is this safe?

I was interested about the CPU so I did a little digging and found this location

`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor\0`
~MHz shows your MHz in hexadecimal.

Comment: Are you trying to overclock your PC?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This registry key is for information only. Its purpose is to pass the CPU
information to applications running on Windows.

Although the permissions on the key allow modification by an administrator,
they will have no effect on the CPU itself, but may cause inefficiencies in some
applications.

Comment: Also, messing with it could trigger some software into becoming nosy about licensing.....

Comment: "inefficiencies" is probably not the right word. Bugs, perhaps. Bugs have a way of making one's workflow less efficient, I suppose, but I doubt that is what you meant.

Comment: Everything under `HKLM\HARDWARE` is for information only. See, for example, https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/managing-the-windows/1565929438/ch11s02.html

Comment: @CodyGray I believe OP means that apps will choose the wrong performance settings, meaning they will do the right stuff, they'll just do it slower (if you lie downwards about the clock speed) or prevent the computer from doing anything else (if you lie upwards).